# Separation of concerns for a "Manager" class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid, separation-of-concerns

I have a Class that "controls" the current application state, `ApplicationStateManager`.
I have an `Enum` that lists the possible states for the application

```
enum ApplicationState
{ 
    Idle,
    Starting,
    Started,
    Stopping,
    Stopped
}
```

`ApplicationStateManager` contains members such as:

```
public static ApplicationState CurrentState = ApplicationState.Idle;

public static void ChangeCurrentState(ApplicationState newState)
{
      CurrentState = newState;
}
```

I could query the `CurrentState` static field by using `ApplicationStateManager.CurrentState;` to see if I can continue code execution or something along these lines.

Now the question is I was trying to separate concerns by having an `ApplicationStateChanger` but the problem is, where to stick the `CurrentState` variable?

Comment: What are you trying to control?

Comment: ...and what concerns are you trying to separate?

Comment: This question needs detail. Please read the post on proper questions

Comment: Do you have a class which decides that the requested change of ApplicationState is valid under current circumstances? Do you have a class to decide upon reception of a signal if the application should change the ApplicationState and to which state? ...

Comment: Generally, wanton use of  "manager" and "service" classes are indication of poor OO designs. Also, this question needs more detail.

Answer (score 3):

If the behavior of your application depends on the state it is in, then this is a clear indicator that you might want to implement it as a [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

This can be achieved using [State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) or [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). You should use former if the number of states is prone to change more often, and the latter if the number of events that can trigger state change is prone to change more often.

Comment: [The Bike Shed #131](http://bikeshed.fm/131) discusses this in dichotomy in some detail (albeit for a different use case)

Answer (score 2):

> I have a Class that "controls" the current application state,
>   ApplicationStateManager

Application should be the only one responsible for its state. It's the fundamental trait of OOP called [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). Any object in OOP is responsible for maintaining its own state.

> Now question is I was trying to separate concerns by having a
>   ApplicationStateChanger

For reasons stated above, there should be no such class. Application should be responsible for changing its state.

> but the problem is, where to stick the CurrentState variable?

You could try to implement a State pattern as was suggested by Vladimir Stokic. But this could be an overkill since *it seems* that your state changing logic is strictly sequential. So another approach is to implement a set of immutable objects:

```
class Idle implements Application
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function next()
    {
        return new Starting();
    }
}

class Starting implements Application
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function next()
    {
        return new Started();
    }
}
```

If you have some mutual to all states functionality, or Context, in terms of State pattern, then the same code could be implemented either with inheritance or with [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), but I'm not aware of your specifics to delve into much details.

Comment: "Application should be the only one who's responsible for its state". Many editors, for example, have dedicated state machines separate from the "application" -- which may even be a completely different code base.

Comment: OK, but it's not OOP then. And OP talks about OOP, as you can see by the tags.

Comment: In case you don't agree, I offer you a deal. I give you a fundamental and trustful link, and you cancel your downvote :) OK, anyway, here is one: https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: I am speaking from decades of working on such editors. It is a common way to do them. Open up any graphical editor and I can assure you, state machines must be separate entities, simply because the "application" is more of a shell and service provider than an editor. The editor state machines are similar to sub-components. It is simply a way to create very complex editors. Visual Studio, for example, works entirely this way. The application itself is only a shell.

Comment: "not OOP": not sure what you mean, perhaps you mean the states are not encapsulated. The state machines are encapsulated in classes. If you read about Harel state charts, you can read about super states and sub states (or parent and child states). There are a number of ways to implement this, but one way is to use base classes for super state transitions, and derived classes for sub state transitions.

Answer (score 0):

> Now question is I was trying to separate concerns by having a ApplicationStateChanger but the problem is, where to stick the CurrentState variable?

The code example provided only shows some getter and setter for the app's state. We need more details in order to discuss anything about concerns.

For now, with these very few details, I would have some Application class, with its getter/setter for its state, and some other external object designated to change these states based on specific circumstances.